# Tor doesn't support architecture arm64?

Tags: tor-install

I get this error when I sudo apt-get update:
"N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'"

Haven't figured out how to solve this. What might cause this error? 
I have Pine64 with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.102-0-pine64-longsleep aarch64)